# UIAlertView textfield keyboard type

Tags: ios, uialertview

I having problem in displaying the textfield keyboard type in the alertview. I want to display numberpad keyboard but it not working.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

switch (alertView.tag) {
    case 1:
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(ProcessDeleteTransaction:) withObject:textField.text waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to set the keyboard type before presenting the alert view?

Comment: No. After presenting the alert view, When the user tapped on the textfield should display the numberpad keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` is a delegate method called when the user clicks a button on an alert view, but the `textField.keyboardType` should be set before `becomeFirstResponder`..so you should set keyboardType property once `[[UIAlertView alloc] init]`

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
UIAlertView *a = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Howdie" message:@"msg" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
a.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField *textField = [a textFieldAtIndex:0];
assert(textField);
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

[a show];
```

Comment: What's the use of this line, `assert(textField);` ? Its also working even if I comment it. Would you please explain?

Comment: @Hemang, asserts are great tools for verifying that some object is not nil. If it's nil the app will crash at that point, letting you know you have a problem immediately, not seconds later.  Make heavy use other as do many experienced programmers. You can disable them in the release build too, so they don't even consume any space.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not really sure why you're posting code for your UIAlertViewDelegate method. Why not configure the keyboard type when the UIAlertView is created?

I actually had never tried this before but had a minute to give it a shot, and this code works fine:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Test" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

[alert show];
```

[image]

Comment: in iOS8, this code gets a bug: Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 3876877096_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];
    [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] becomeFirstResponder];
}
```